# splitting the file and rearrangement

Tags: pandas, dataframe

My text file contain data of temp variation

```
#
1  2
2  4
3  4
# 
6  1
3  2
1  7
```

I want the column values to be splitted at # and generate the new files by appending the splitted files

expected output1

```
1 6
2 3
3 1
```

expected output2

```
2 1
4 2
4 7
```

Comment: It looks like a straight-forward procedure. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more complex problem than it seems at first glance. I had to carefully look at the example output to fully see what was going on.

Simulated text file:

```
sim_txt = io.StringIO('''
#
1  2
2  4
3  4
# 
6  1
3  2
1  7
''')

df = pd.read_csv(sim_txt, sep='\s+', header=None, names=[0,1])

df_out = df.assign(out=df[0].str.contains('#').cumsum()) \
    .pivot(columns=['out']).apply(lambda x: x.shift(-len(x)//2) if x.name[1]==2 else x) \
    .dropna().astype(int)

print(df_out)

     0     1   
out  1  2  1  2
1    1  6  2  1
2    2  3  4  2
3    3  1  4  7
```

Then save to individual files:

```
for c in df_out.columns.get_level_values(0).unique():
    df_out.loc[1:,c].to_csv(fr'd:\jchtempnew\SO\output{c+1}.txt', index=None, header=None, sep=' ')

output1

1 6
2 3
3 1

output2

2 1
4 2
4 7
```